# XML output help required

Tags: oracle

I am trying to build output in following format in XML from table data but I am facing some issue with output to create XML element and attributes correctly in expected format.

**Data sample table:**

```
select 'textxml' fileformat,9988335 dept,'SECTION123' startposition,'SECTION123'endposition,'CREATE' action,'MUMBAI'select_for,'ANDHERI' loc,7 Duration
from dual
union ALL
select 'textxml' fileformat,9988335 dept,'Area1' startposition,'Area1'endposition,'CREATE' action,'Pune'select_for,null loc,5 Duration
from dual;
```

**Expected Output:**

```
<Data> 
                <Details source="A"> 
                                <pack>COMPNAME</pack>  
                                <ref>textxml</ref>  
                                <dept>9988335</dept> 
                                <MAIN code="TASKCREATE"> 
                                                <StartPosition>SECTION123</StartPosition> 
                                                <EndPosition>SECTION123</EndPosition> 
                                                <Reference Code="Action">CREATE</Reference> 
                                                <Reference Code="Select For">Mumbai</Reference> 
                                                <Reference Code="Location">Andheri</Reference> 
                                                <ReferenceNumber Code="Duration">7</ReferenceNumber> 
                                </MAIN> 
                               <MAIN code="TASKCREATE"> 
                                                <StartPosition>Area1</StartPosition> 
                                                <EndPosition>Area1</EndPosition> 
                                                <Reference Code="Action">CREATE</Reference> 
                                                <Reference Code="Select For">Pune</Reference> 
                                                <ReferenceNumber Code="Duration">5</ReferenceNumber> 
                                </MAIN> 
                                
                </Details> 
</Data>
```

**Written Query which failed for expected output:**

```
select XMLELEMENT("Data",XMLELEMENT("Details",XMLATTRIBUTES('A' as "sourcesystem"),
XMLAgg(
XMLForest('COMPNAME' as pack, a.fileformat as ref, a.dept as dept
,XMLELEMENT("MAIN",XMLATTRIBUTES('SELECTFOR' as "code")) as test
))))
from (select 'textxml' fileformat,9988335 dept,'SECTION123' startposition,'SECTION123'endposition,'CREATE' action,'MUMBAI'select_for,'ANDHERI' loc,7 Duration
from dual
union ALL
select 'textxml' fileformat,9988335 dept,'Area1' startposition,'Area1'endposition,'CREATE' action,'Pune'select_for,null loc,5 Duration
from dual
)a;
```

Comment: Do you have an XML schema?

Comment: Please try to use useful titles here. "Help Required" is not a good summary of the problem you are facing. Would you edit your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT XMLSERIALIZE(
         CONTENT XMLELEMENT(
           "Data",
           XMLELEMENT(
             "Details",
             XMLATTRIBUTES('A' as "source"),
             XMLFOREST(
               'COMPNAME' AS "pack",
               fileformat AS "ref",
               dept AS "dept"
             ),
             XMLAgg(
               XMLELEMENT(
                 "Main",
                 XMLATTRIBUTES('TASKCREATE' as "code"),
                 XMLELEMENT("StartPosition", startposition),
                 XMLELEMENT("EndPosition", endposition),
                 XMLELEMENT("Reference", XMLATTRIBUTES('Action' AS "Code"), action),
                 XMLELEMENT("Reference", XMLATTRIBUTES('Select For' AS "Code"), select_for),
                 XMLELEMENT("Reference", XMLATTRIBUTES('Location' AS "Code"), loc),
                 XMLELEMENT("ReferenceNumber", XMLATTRIBUTES('Duration' AS "Code"), duration)
               )
             )
           )
         ) AS CLOB
         INDENT SIZE = 2
       ) AS data
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY
       fileformat,
       dept;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (fileformat, dept, startposition, endposition, action, select_for, loc, duration) AS
select 'textxml',9988335,'SECTION123' ,'SECTION123','CREATE','MUMBAI','ANDHERI',7 from dual union ALL
select 'textxml',9988335,'Area1','Area1','CREATE','Pune',null,5 from dual;
```

Outputs:

| DATA |
| --- |
| <Data> <Details source="A"> <pack>COMPNAME</pack> <ref>textxml</ref> <dept>9988335</dept> <Main code="TASKCREATE"> <StartPosition>SECTION123</StartPosition> <EndPosition>SECTION123</EndPosition> <Reference Code="Action">CREATE</Reference> <Reference Code="Select For">MUMBAI</Reference> <Reference Code="Location">ANDHERI</Reference> <ReferenceNumber Code="Duration">7</ReferenceNumber> </Main> <Main code="TASKCREATE"> <StartPosition>Area1</StartPosition> <EndPosition>Area1</EndPosition> <Reference Code="Action">CREATE</Reference> <Reference Code="Select For">Pune</Reference> <Reference Code="Location"/> <ReferenceNumber Code="Duration">5</ReferenceNumber> </Main> </Details> </Data> |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RPFbm6lQ)